# img not showing in html, while online urls are working

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to build my portfolio website using Django, but I have trouble adding my photo. Even if I specify the correct path it doesn't display... However, an online image is displayed properly.

```html
<html lang="en"><head><link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous"></head>
<body>
  <!-- Title Bar -->
  <section class="section-gap">
    <div class="row featurette">
      <div class="col-md-7">
        <h2 class="fs-1 featurette-heading">PARAMASIVAN T</h2>
        <div class="fs-2 text-muted">Web Developer</div>
        <p class="lead">“Digital design is like painting, except the paint never dries.”</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <img src="D:\Django_Projects\porfolio\mysite\myapp\templates\myapp\profile.png" alt="profile">  
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you expect everyone who visits your site, to have your images on their computer in a very specific location?

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder called `static` in the root of the project and place the image there. After that, update your html file as follows:

```html
{% load static %}
    <section class="section-gap">
        <div class="row featurette">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h2 class="fs-1 featurette-heading">PARAMASIVAN T</h2>
                <div class="fs-2 text-muted">Web Developer</div>
                <p class="lead">“Digital design is like painting, except the paint never dries.”</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
              <img src="{% static 'profile.png' %}" alt="profile">
            </div>
    </section>
```